# Pandas : Select columns based on the columns sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df   = pd.DataFrame({'row_one': [0,1,1], 'second': [0,0,1], 'third': [0,1,1], 'forth': [0,0,0], 'fifth': [0,0,0]})
```

[image]

I want to select columns where the sum of each column is more than 1

[image]

What I have tried:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame((df.sum(axis=0) >=1))
df[df_1[df_1[0]==True].index]
```

Is there any more efficient method?

Comment: No, that is selecting rows while I am trying to choose columns. :)

Comment: I am sure you are clever enough to change a `1` into a `0` and use `loc` ;)

Comment: I thought it's good to post a question for future reference, also changing just `0` won't solve the issue :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been closed.  I needed a way to get a list of variable names where the columns of that variable was not 0 or NaN.  There were many solutions on selecting rows based on a condition, not columns.  While going from one to another may be trivial for @mozway, it is not necessarily trivial for a new python / pandas user.  This question and the solution below helped me more than the link posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for select all rows and columns by mask if performance is important:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.sum() >=1]
print (df)
   row_one  second  third
0        0       0      0
1        1       0      1
2        1       1      1
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.to_numpy().sum(axis=0) >=1]
```

Comment: @U12-Forward - Ya, unfortunately dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Or use with transposing:

```
>>> df.T[df.sum() >= 1].T
   row_one  second  third
0        0       0      0
1        1       0      1
2        1       1      1
>>>
```

That filters the transposed dataframe, that behaves regularly.

Or you could get the column names with:

```
>>> df[df.sum()[df.sum() >= 1].index]
   row_one  second  third
0        0       0      0
1        1       0      1
2        1       1      1
>>>
```

Or with `drop`:

```
>>> df.drop(df.columns[df.sum() < 1], axis=1)
   row_one  second  third
0        0       0      0
1        1       0      1
2        1       1      1
>>>
```

Comment: IMO worthless to add another solution, better delete

Comment: Ya, now it is OK.

Comment: @mozway Using `T` is also short and kinda slick, so I guess it's fine

Comment: @U12-Forward I don't think so, it's more cryptic. Here this is really a simple task, no need to add weird transformations just to have a different solution. Honestly to ask this question one need to be a beginner, so the simplest the solution, the better…

Comment: @mozway Added a `drop`.